# Natural transformation arrow

Tags: xy-pic

I'm trying to do the following with `xymatrix`:

[image]

This is a diagram I drew sometime ago... But now I don't have the source and I can't remember how I did it, nor can I find an easy, simple way to do it.

More specifically, what I forgot how to do is the vertical arrow in the middle.

Comment: Are you interested in other ways of drawing such diagrams, for example in TikZ? If yes, we could show how this example would look with TikZ, or PSTricks.

Comment: @Stefan: Personally, I use xymatrix and I'm happy with it, but perhaps it is valuable to the community that the question be answered most completely; I'll leave it to your judgement. Thank you for the interest.

Comment: I just wanted to show you possibilities, and well readable syntax and fine output of TikZ. No need to extend if you don't really wish it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 2cell module is what you need:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip,2cell]{xy}
\UseTwocells

\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix@C+2pc{
\mathsf{CRing} \rtwocell^{\mathsf{GL}_n}_{U}{\;\;\;\det} & \mathsf{Grp}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I really used this? My (lack of) memory amazes me. Thank you, this is nice. However, how could I get the arrows to curve a little bit more?

Comment: @BrunoStonek `\rtwocell<6>...`; page 45 of `xyrefer.pdf`