# How to center twocell arrows

Tags: horizontal-alignment, xy-pic

I'm using `2cell` (as in this previous question of mine: [Natural transformation arrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41782/natural-transformation-arrow) ).

I'd like to know how to center not just the `twocell` double arrow, but arrow with its name too. A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

This diagram is generated by the following code:

```
$\xymatrix@C+3pc{J\rtwocell<4>^{\Delta(C)}_{\Delta(C')}{\; \; \; \; \; \Delta(f)} & \C}$
```

I'd like to know how to center the whole `$\Downarrow \Delta(f)$`, not just the `$\Downarrow$`.

Comment: Is TikZ also possible?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I'd rather stick to xypic.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether this can be done with `twocell`, but with regular `xypic` you can certainly achieve it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix@C+3pc{
J \ar@{}[r]|{\Downarrow \Delta(f)} \ar@/_/[r]_{\Delta(C)} \ar@/^/[r]^{\Delta(C)}& C
}
\]

\[
\xymatrix{
J \ar@/_/[rr]_{\Delta(C)} \ar@/^/[rr]^{\Delta(C)}& {\Downarrow \Delta(f)} & C
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: resulting diagrams]

Next time please post a complete MWE, even in follow-up questions.