# Problem using twocell in xypic

Tags: xy-pic

I tried using the `\rtwocell` command to produce twocells in a commutative diagram and my LaTeX installation (TeX Live on a Mac) does not recognize it.  It seems to recognize everything else I have tried with `xypic`.  Are there are known issues with `xypic` on TeX Live?

This is the example I tried:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,2cell]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[ \xymatrix{A\rtwocell^f_g{\eta}& B} \]
\end{document}
```

This is the error that is produced

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \xyeatall@ \everyentry@ A\rtwocell 
                                              ^f_g{\eta }
l.4 \[ \xymatrix{A\rtwocell^f_g{\eta}& B}
                                          \]
```

Comment: Please, next time add the code and the error message to the question, rather than in comments. Looking forward for other contributions from you on the site.

Answer (score 2):

As the manual says in a rather hidden place, you have to say

```
\UseTwocells
```

after loading `xy` (page 44).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,2cell]{xy}
\UseTwocells

\begin{document}
\[ \xymatrix{A\rtwocell^f_g{\eta}& B} \]
\end{document}
```

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41784/4427

There should be a new syntax for two-cells, but unfortunately the manual doesn't describe it.

Comment: Thanks, I did not see that hidden place.  Next time I will post the example with the question.  Thanks again.

Comment: @PrakashPanangaden It's so well hidden that every time I need to read the manual for finding it. :)