# Natural transformation arrow with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do you draw natural transformation arrows as mentioned in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41782/natural-transformation-arrow) but using TikZ rather than xy? More generally, is it possible to draw edges between edge labels, from an edge label to a node, and from a node to an edge label or is it necessary to explicitly construct a node in order to draw an edge? Does providing an edge label in the path environment implicitly construct a node that can be used as the source and target of another edge? I would like to do this using the matrix and path environments in TikZ if possible.

**Example**:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{tikzpicture}[description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]
    \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em,
    column sep=2.0em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
    { \mathcal{D} & & \mathcal{J} \\
      \mathcal{C} & & \\ };
    \path[->,font=\scriptsize]
    (m-1-1) edge[loop left] node[auto] {$ F \circ G $} (m-1-1)
    (m-1-1.20) edge node[auto] {$ G $} (m-1-3.160)
    (m-1-3.200) edge node[auto] {$ F $} (m-1-1.340)
    (m-1-1) edge node[left] {$ H $} (m-2-1);    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: example diagram]

How can I connect *F◦G* and *H* with a curved natural transformation arrow ⟹? Feel free to rearrange the diagram if you'd like.

Comment: I think you would be quite happy when reading the manual of [`tikz-cd`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz-cd). Feels like it is what you need.

Comment: Thank you **percusse** for the information on tikz-cd, I did not know it existed.

Comment: Anyway, in the meantime, I've provided a solution to your new request. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As **percusse** mentions in his comment, the [tikz-cd](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) package offers you a convenient set of macros to draw commutative diagrams; here's a little example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=huge]
\textbf{CRing}
  \arrow[bend left=50]{r}[name=U,label=above:$\scriptstyle\mathrm{GL}_n$]{}
  \arrow[bend right=50]{r}[name=D,label=below:$\scriptstyle U$]{} &
\textbf{Grp}
  \arrow[shorten <=10pt,shorten >=10pt,Rightarrow,to path={(U) -- node[label=right:$\det$] {} (D)}]{}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since originally the question asked for a `TikZ` solution using a matrix of nodes, here's a "pure" TikZ possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=2cm] (cd)
{
   \textbf{CRing} & \textbf{Grp} \\
};
\draw[->] (cd-1-1) to[bend left=50] node[label=above:$\scriptstyle\mathrm{GL}_n$] (U) {} (cd-1-2);
\draw[->] (cd-1-1) to[bend right=50,name=D] node[label=below:$\scriptstyle U$] (V) {} (cd-1-2);
\draw[double,double equal sign distance,-implies,shorten >=10pt,shorten <=10pt] 
  (U) -- node[label=right:$\det$] {} (V);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An answer to the edit to the original question, showing two possibilities (a curved double arrow, and a straight one):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]
    \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em,
    column sep=2.0em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
    { \mathcal{D} & & \mathcal{J} \\
      \mathcal{C} & & \\ };
    \path[->,font=\scriptsize]
    (m-1-1) edge[loop left] node[auto] (fg) {$ F \circ G $} (m-1-1)
    (m-1-1.20) edge node[auto] {$ G $} (m-1-3.160)
    (m-1-3.200) edge node[auto] {$ F $} (m-1-1.340)
    (m-1-1) edge node[left] (h) {$ H $} (m-2-1);
    \draw[double,double equal sign distance,-implies] (fg.290) -- (h.150);    
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]
    \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em,
    column sep=2.0em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
    { \mathcal{D} & & \mathcal{J} \\
      \mathcal{C} & & \\ };
    \path[->,font=\scriptsize]
    (m-1-1) edge[loop left] node[auto] (fg) {$ F \circ G $} (m-1-1)
    (m-1-1.20) edge node[auto] {$ G $} (m-1-3.160)
    (m-1-3.200) edge node[auto] {$ F $} (m-1-1.340)
    (m-1-1) edge node[left] (h) {$ H $} (m-2-1);
    \draw[double,double equal sign distance,-implies] (fg.290) to[out=-90,in=180] (h.180);    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here's the corresponding code using `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=huge,row sep=huge]
\mathcal{D}
  \arrow[loop left]{}[name=fg]{F \circ G}
  \rar[start anchor=30, end anchor=151]{G}
  \arrow{d}[name=h,swap]{H} & 
\mathcal{J}\lar[start anchor=196, end anchor=-14]{F} \\
\mathcal{C}
\arrow[shorten >=4pt,Rightarrow,to path={(fg.290) -- (h.175)}]{}
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=huge,row sep=huge]
\mathcal{D}
  \arrow[loop left]{}[name=fg]{F \circ G}
  \rar[start anchor=30, end anchor=151]{G}
  \arrow{d}[swap,name=h]{H} & 
\mathcal{J}\lar[start anchor=196, end anchor=-14]{F} \\
\mathcal{C}
\arrow[shorten >=3pt,Rightarrow,to path={(fg.290) to[out=-90,in=180] (h)}]{}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To add a label to the double arrow (as requested in a comment), you can use an additional node; here's an example using both approaches (the first one using `tikz-cd` and the second one using "pure" `TikZ`):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=huge,row sep=huge]
\mathcal{D}
  \arrow[loop left]{}[name=fg]{F \circ G}
  \rar[start anchor=30, end anchor=151]{G}
  \arrow{d}[swap,name=h]{H} & 
\mathcal{J}\lar[start anchor=196, end anchor=-14]{F} \\
\mathcal{C}
\arrow[shorten >=1pt,Rightarrow,to path={(fg.290) to[out=-90,in=180] node[xshift=-3.5mm] {$\tau$} (h)}]{}
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzpicture}[description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]
    \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em,
    column sep=2.0em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
    { \mathcal{D} & & \mathcal{J} \\
      \mathcal{C} & & \\ };
    \path[->,font=\scriptsize]
    (m-1-1) edge[loop left] node[auto] (fg) {$ F \circ G $} (m-1-1)
    (m-1-1.20) edge node[auto] {$ G $} (m-1-3.160)
    (m-1-3.200) edge node[auto] {$ F $} (m-1-1.340)
    (m-1-1) edge node[left] (h) {$ H $} (m-2-1);
    \draw[double,double equal sign distance,-implies] (fg.290) to[out=-90,in=180] node[xshift=-3.5mm] {$\tau$} (h.180);    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you **Gonzalo** for the examples and pointing me to tikz-cd. I probably wouldn't have requested to use matrix and path if I knew tikz-cd existed.

Comment: tikz-cd uses a matrix but the matrix is hidden.

Comment: Thank you very much for the additional examples Gonzalo. How can I add an edge label to the natural transformation arrow?

Comment: @camrn86: You're welcome. Please see my updated answer for an example on how to add the label.

Comment: That is nice and elaborate! +1.

Comment: Wow. Thanks again Gonzalo! I have learned a lot from this exchange.

Answer (score 8):

I don't respect some initial conditions because I don't understand what it's interesting to use a matrix for two vertices. I think matrix is very useful but only for complex structures.

Here we need two lines to place the main nodes. I used `outer sep=4pt` to put the arrows at right places. Then I place two nodes in the middle of each arrows. I named these nodes to be able to draw the last double arrow. The option fo this arrow are complex, so I think it's preferable to use a style.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{dbl/.style={double,
                     double equal sign distance,
                     -implies,
                     shorten >=10pt,
                     shorten <=10pt}}

\begin{tikzpicture} [every node/.style={outer sep=4pt}]
 \node  (A) at (0,0)  {\textbf{CRing}}; 
 \node  (B) at (4,0)  {\textbf{Grp}};

 \draw[->]  (A.north)  to [bend left = 30]  node[above] (C) {$\scriptstyle\mathrm{GL}_n$} (B.north);
 \draw[->]  (A.south)  to [bend right= 30]  node[below] (D) {$\scriptstyle U$}            (B.south);   
 \draw[dbl]   (C)      to                   node[right]     {$\det$}                      (D);
\end{tikzpicture}     

\end{document}
```

[image]

The aim of this method is to be able to scale the figure like I want, now two examples :

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{dbl/.style={double,
                     double equal sign distance,
                     -implies,
                     shorten >=10pt,
                     shorten <=10pt}}

\begin{tikzpicture} [every node/.style={outer sep=4pt},yscale=1.5]
 \node  (A) at (0,0)  {\textbf{CRing}}; 
 \node  (B) at (4,0)  {\textbf{Grp}};

 \draw[->]  (A.north) to [bend left = 30]  node[above] (C) {$\scriptstyle\mathrm{GL}_n$}  (B.north);
 \draw[->]  (A.south) to [bend right= 30]  node[below] (D) {$\scriptstyle U$}             (B.south);   
 \draw[dbl]   (C)     to                   node[right]     {$\det$}                       (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture} [every node/.style={outer sep=4pt},xscale=1.5,yscale=1.25]
 \node  (A) at (0,0)  {\textbf{CRing}}; 
 \node  (B) at (4,0)  {\textbf{Grp}};

 \draw[->]  (A.north)  to [bend left = 30]  node[above] (C) {$\scriptstyle\mathrm{GL}_n$} (B.north);
 \draw[->]  (A.south)  to [bend right= 30]  node[below] (D) {$\scriptstyle U$}            (B.south);   
 \draw[dbl]   (C)      to                   node[right]     {$\det$}                      (D);
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the examples **Altermundus**. The reason I asked to use matrix is that I have more complicated diagrams in mind. I just linked to that previous post because it had an example of a natural transformation arrow between two edge labels. That is nice to be able to scale the drawing. I think I will stick with tikz-cd for what seems to be the relative simplicity of the syntax, but that might change with more complicated diagrams. Is it possible to scale a diagram like this with tikz-cd?

Comment: I don't know, I never use tikz-cd. I try with only with your example and it seems not easy to do. Perhaps scale a matrix is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add that it can be very useful to write a macro for that. For example as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\nat}[6][large]{%
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&, column sep=#1]
    #2\ar[bend left=40,""{name=U}]{r}{#4}\ar[bend right=40,',""{name=D}]{r}{#5}\& #3
          \ar[shorten <=10pt,shorten >=10pt,Rightarrow,from=U,to=D]{d}{~#6}
    \end{tikzcd}
}
\newcommand{\te}[1]{\text{#1}}
\newcommand{\tf}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
```

The command \nat takes 6 arguments but includes one default argument for the column separation, so you just need to specify 5.
Then your document looks as follows:

```
\begin{document}

    \nat{\tf{CRing}}{\tf{Mon}}{M_n}{U}{\te{det}}
    \nat[huge]{\tf{CRing}}{\tf{Mon}}{M_n}{U}{\te{det}}

\end{document}`
```

[image]