# Creating double arrow / parallel arrows with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I made this diagram and the only thing I want are two parallel arrows that go from node A to B and vice versa, so that I can label both arrows differently, because both nodes interact. You can choose which "nodes" of the matrix you use.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,matrix}
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=6em,
column sep=6em, text height=3ex, text depth=0.5ex]
{ & (T_t)_{t\geq 0} & \\
(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A})) & & (R(\lambda,\mathcal{A}))_{\lambda\in \rho(\mathcal{A})} \\ };
\path[->] (m-2-3) edge (m-1-2);
\path[->] (m-1-2) edge (m-2-1) edge node[above left] {$ \mathcal{A}f=\lim_{t\downarrow 0}\frac{P_tf-f}{t}$} (m-2-1);
;
\path[->] (m-2-1) edge (m-2-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You might find this question and its answers helpful: [How to draw labeled parallel arrows in commutative diagram with TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48216/how-to-draw-labeled-parallel-arrows-in-commutative-diagram-with-tikz)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Natural transformation arrow with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55320/natural-transformation-arrow-with-tikz)

Answer (score 28):

Here are three possibilities:

- draw 2 arrows, but bend them with `bend left=<degrees>` or `bend right=<degrees>`
- draw double arrows with `double` option
- draw two arrows leaving the nodes at different angles via `node.angle`

Here some example code:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,circle] (A) at (90:3) {A};
\node[draw,circle] (B) at (210:3) {B};
\node[draw,circle] (C) at (330:3) {C};
\draw[-latex] (A) to[bend right=10] node[above,rotate=60] {$A\Rightarrow B$} (B);
\draw[-latex] (B) to[bend right=10] node[below,rotate=60] {$B\Rightarrow A$} (A);
\draw[-latex] (A) to[bend right=10] node[below,rotate=300] {$A\Rightarrow C$} (C);
\draw[-latex] (C) to[bend right=10] node[above,rotate=300] {$C\Rightarrow A$} (A);
\draw[-latex] (B) to[bend right=10] node[below] {$B\Rightarrow C$} (C);
\draw[-latex] (C) to[bend right=10] node[above] {$C\Rightarrow B$} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,circle] (A) at (90:3) {A};
\node[draw,circle] (B) at (210:3) {B};
\node[draw,circle] (C) at (330:3) {C};
\draw[latex'-latex',double] (A) -- node[label=150:A-B,label=330:B-A] {} (B);
\draw[latex'-latex',double] (A) -- node[label=30:A-C,label=210:C-A] {} (C);
\draw[latex'-latex',double] (B) -- node[label=90:B-C,label=270:C-B] {} (C);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,circle] (A) at (90:3) {A};
\node[draw,circle] (B) at (210:3) {B};
\node[draw,circle] (C) at (330:3) {C};
\draw[-open triangle 45] (A.225) -- node[rotate=60,above] {A-B} (B.75);
\draw[open triangle 45-] (A.255) -- node[rotate=60,below] {B-A} (B.45);
\draw[-open triangle 45] (A.285) -- node[rotate=300,below] {A-C} (C.135);
\draw[open triangle 45-] (A.315) -- node[rotate=300,above] {C-A} (C.105);
\draw[-open triangle 45] (B.345) -- node[rotate=0,below] {A-C} (C.195);
\draw[open triangle 45-] (B.15) -- node[rotate=0,above] {C-A} (C.165);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And the resulting image:

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** Sure it can be done with the matrix environment. But I just realized (again) that the variable width of the nodes causes problems when using the `node.angle` notation. This can be circumvented by using the `calc` library, although this solution also isn't perfect: in the second example, all pairs of arrows are horizontaly spaced 2 millimeters, but the distances look different. I'll think about this a little more.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,matrix}
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=6em,
column sep=6em, text height=3ex, text depth=0.5ex]
{ & (T_t)_{t\geq 0} & \\
(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A})) & & (R(\lambda,\mathcal{A}))_{\lambda\in \rho(\mathcal{A})} \\ };
\path[->] (m-2-3.160) edge (m-1-2.270);
\path[->] (m-2-3.140) edge (m-1-2.290);
\path[->] (m-1-2) edge (m-2-1) edge node[above left] {$ \mathcal{A}f=\lim_{t\downarrow 0}\frac{P_tf-f}{t}$} (m-2-1);
;
\path[->] (m-2-1) edge (m-2-3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,matrix}
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=6em,
column sep=6em, text height=3ex, text depth=0.5ex]
{ & (T_t)_{t\geq 0} & \\
(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A})) & & (R(\lambda,\mathcal{A}))_{\lambda\in \rho(\mathcal{A})} \\ };
\path[->] ($(m-2-3.north)+(-0.1,0)$) edge ($(m-1-2.south)+(+0.1,0)$);
\path[<-] ($(m-2-3.north)+(+0.1,0)$) edge ($(m-1-2.south)+(+0.3,0)$);

\path[->] ($(m-1-2.south)+(-0.3,0)$) edge node[above left] {$ \mathcal{A}f=\lim_{t\downarrow 0}\frac{P_tf-f}{t}$} ($(m-2-1.north)+(-0.1,0)$);
\path[<-] ($(m-1-2.south)+(-0.1,0)$) edge node[below right] {$\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\varepsilon\zeta\eta$} ($(m-2-1.north)+(+0.1,0)$);
;
\path[->] ($(m-2-1.east)+(0,-0.1)$) edge ($(m-2-3.west)+(0,-0.1)$);
\path[<-] ($(m-2-1.east)+(0,+0.1)$) edge ($(m-2-3.west)+(0,+0.1)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible to do that with the matrix environment?