# Can't get example of 2-cell from xy-pic reference to work

Tags: xy-pic

I'm trying to recreate example 2 from the xypic reference manual (http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/doc/xyrefer.pdf p.43 )

```
\diagram
A\ruppertwocell^f{\alpha}
\rlowertwocell_h{\beta}
\rto_(.35)g & B\\
\enddiagram
```

[image]

I got the first example working in the following manner with inspiration from [Natural transformation arrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41782/natural-transformation-arrow/41784#41784)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip,2cell]{xy}
\UseTwocells
\xyoption{2cell}
\begin{document}
$$
\xymatrix@C+2pc{
A \rtwocell<6>^{f}_{g}{\;\;\;\alpha} & B}
$$

\end{document}
```

But just pasting the second example gives me

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.15 \diagram
```

and changing \diagram to \xymatrix@C+2pc{... as above gives me:

```
...
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xypic/xy2cell.tex
 Xy-pic option: Two-cell feature v.3.7 not reloaded) (./test2cells.aux)
<xymatrix 2x1 20> <xymatrix
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...atall@ \everyentry@ A\ruppertwocell 
                                                  ^f{\alpha } \rlowertwocell...
l.19 \rto_(.35)g & B}
                     $$
```

What is the proper way to get this to work in xy-pic? Should I really be using the diagrams package?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Note that the part of the `xy` manual which you reference includes "Bug: This document still uses version 2-style commmands, as described in appendix B." looking at Appendix B, `xyoption{v2}` should be used although this only shifts the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation says (just above that second diagram:
"**Bug**: This document still uses version 2-style
commmands, as described in appendix B."

To use version 2 commands like `\diagram`, include `\xyoption{v2}` or give the package option `v2`.
And to use the half cells, use `\UseAllTwoCells` instead of just `\UseTwocells`. And please don't use `$$` in LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,v2,cmtip,2cell]{xy}
\UseAllTwocells
\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix@C+2pc{
A \rtwocell<6>^{f}_{g}{\;\;\;\alpha} & B}
\]

\diagram
A\ruppertwocell^f{\alpha}
\rlowertwocell_h{\beta}
\rto_(.35)g & B\\
\enddiagram

\end{document}
```

Without the v2, the second diagram can be given as

```
\xymatrix@C+2pc{
A\ruppertwocell^f{\alpha}
\rlowertwocell_h{\beta}
\ar[r]_(.35)g & B}
```